# How to autofocus an IonInput/OtpInput field in (Ionic + React.js App), I have already tried all the solutions out there

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, input, autofocus, ionic-react

> I have an otp input field and I want it to be autofocused on initial rendering(using hooks,
> smart and dumb component)
> The field is inside an IonModal

```
import OtpInput from "react-otp-input"; 
import {IonInput, IonModal} from '@ionic/react';

<IonModal isOpen={true} cssClass={classes.someClass} showBackdrop={false} >
  <OtpInput
    shouldAutoFocus={true}
    value={props.otp}
    numInputs={6}
  />
</IonModal>
```

> I want specifically OtpInput but I also tried with IonInput, it's also not autofocusable

```
<IonInput
    autofocus={true}
    type="number"
    label="Enter OTP"
/>
```

> tried autofocus attribute, document.querySelecterAll, couldnt try document.getElementById cause
> somehow Id is not showing on the element

> What I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
<ion-input autofocus="true"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Already tried, but somehow it's not working,